# .snapshot() method isn't accepting SnapshotParameters()

Tags: java, javafx, snapshot

I am trying to take a snapshot of a scene (which is essentially a diagram maker) and store it as a .png file. However, as the top part of the scene has menu bars, I want to ensure that only the part of the scene below the menu bars is getting captured. I thought of using Snapshot Parameters to ensure this, but for whatever reason the snapshot method doesn't accept my SnapshotParameters class.

Here is the method that takes the snapshot. The issue is that scene.snapshot will not accept the SnapshotParameters param. The code below will work perfectly accept it isn't able to "crop out" the top part of the scene which contains the menubars.

```
    public void exportDiagram() throws IOException {
        TextInputDialog inputDialog = new TextInputDialog();
        inputDialog.getDialogPane().setContentText("Save image as:");
        inputDialog.showAndWait();
        TextField userInput = inputDialog.getEditor();
        Scene scene = main.getScene();
        SnapshotParameters param = new SnapshotParameters();
        param.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(0, 23, 600, 377));
        WritableImage imgReturn = scene.snapshot(null);
        File file = new File(userInput.getText() + ".png");
        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(imgReturn, null), "png", file);
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: It seems like the better solution would just be to snapshot whatever node contains what you want to be in the png file.